# How to make your player get pass the first level in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, multi-level

**My game has been created but I would really like to add a second level to it how could I go about and creating another level for my racing game? I have created the first level to it but I would want to add another level as soon as my car reaches the end of the of the finish line. How can I do that? Thank you in advance!**

```
import pygame, random
from time import sleep

pygame.init()
# music/sounds
CarSound = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/CAR+Peels+Out.wav")
CarSound_two = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/racing01.wav")
CarSound_three = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/RACECAR.wav")
CarSound_four = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/formula+1.wav")
Crowds = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/cheer_8k.wav")
Crowds_two = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/applause7.wav")
Crowds_three = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/crowdapplause1.wav")
final_tone = pygame.mixer.Sound("image/Victory.wav")
music = pygame.mixer.music.load("image/Led Zeppelin - Rock And Roll (Alternate Mix) (Official Music Video).mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
bg = pygame.image.load('image/Crowds.png')
main_img = pygame.image.load("image/img4.png")
main_img2 = pygame.image.load("image/img5.png")
side_img = pygame.image.load("image/bull2.png")
side_img2 = pygame.image.load("image/fox.png")
pauseimg = pygame.image.load("image/pause2.png")



clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pause = False

# Setting up our colors that we are going to use
GREEN = (20, 255, 140)
GREY = (210, 210, 210)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)
BLACKWHITE = (96, 96, 96)
BLACK = (105, 105, 105)
RGREEN = (0, 66, 37)
LIGHT_RED = (200, 0, 0)
BRIGHT_GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
DARK_BLUE = (0, 0, 139)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
NAVY = (0, 0 , 128)
DARK_OLIVE_GREEN = (85, 107, 47)
YELLOW_AND_GREEN = (154, 205, 50)


SCREENWIDTH = 400
SCREENHEIGHT = 500

size = (SCREENWIDTH, SCREENHEIGHT)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("Car Racing")
Icon = pygame.image.load("image/redca_iconr.png")
pygame.display.set_icon((Icon))
# This will be a list that will contain all the sprites we intend to use in our game.
# all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# player
playerIMG = pygame.image.load("image/red_racecar.png")
playerX = 280
playerY = 450
playerCar_position = 0

# player2
playerIMG_two = pygame.image.load("image/greencar.png")
playerX_two = 150
playerY_two = 450
playerCar_position_two = 0

# player3
playerIMG_three = pygame.image.load("image/Orangecar.png")
playerX_three = 60
playerY_three = 450
playerCar_position_three = 0

# player4
playerIMG_four = pygame.image.load("image/yellowcar2.png")
playerX_four = 210
playerY_four = 450
playerCar_position_four = 0


# Putting cars to the screen
def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerIMG, (x, y))


def player_two(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerIMG_two, (x, y))


def player_three(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerIMG_three, (x, y))


def player_four(x, y):
    screen.blit(playerIMG_four, (x, y))


finish_text = ""
font2 = pygame.font.SysFont("Papyrus", 65)
players_finished = []
next_level = 0
placings = ["1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th"]


smallfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Papyrus", 15)
normalfont = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 25)
differntfont = pygame.font.SysFont("futura", 25)

def level(next_level):
    level = normalfont.render("Level: "+ str(next_level), True, BLACK)
    screen.blit(level, [250, 10])

def score(score):
    text = smallfont.render("Race cars passing: " + str(score), True, RGREEN)
    screen.blit(text, [145, 490])



def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()


def message_display(text):
    largText = pygame.font.Font("Mulish-Regular.ttf", 15)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largText)
    TextRect.center = ((SCREENWIDTH / 1), (SCREENHEIGHT / 1))
    screen.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

text_two = normalfont.render("Start new game?", 5, (0, 66, 37))
time_to_blit = None

pygame.display.flip()


def button(msg, x, y, w, h, iC, aC, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x + w > mouse[0] > x and y + h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, iC, (x, y, w, h))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "Play":
                game_loop()

            if action == "unpause":
                unpause()

            elif action == "Quit":

                pygame.quit()
                quit()

    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, aC, (x, y, w, h))

    newtext = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 25)
    textSurf, textReact = text_objects(msg, newtext)
    textReact.center = ((x + (100 / 2))), (y + (h / 2))
    screen.blit(textSurf, textReact)

    newtext = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 25)
    textSurf, textReact = text_objects("QUIT!", newtext)
    textReact.center = ((260 + (100 / 2))), (40 + (50 / 2))
    screen.blit(textSurf, textReact)

def unpause():
    global pause
    pause = False

def paused():
    newtext = pygame.font.SysFont("arial", 25)
    textSurf, textReact = text_objects("paused", newtext)
    textReact.center = ((100 + (100 / 2))), (100 + (100 / 2))
    screen.blit(textSurf, textReact)
    screen.fill(WHITE)

    while pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
        screen.blit(pauseimg, (0, 1))
        button("   Continue!?", 40, 40, 125, 50, DARK_BLUE, BLUE, "unpause")
        button("QUIT!", 260, 40, 100, 50, LIGHT_RED, RED, "Quit")

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)


def game_intro():
    intro = True
    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        screen.fill(BLACK)
        text = normalfont.render("Super Racer!", 8, (0, 66, 37))
        new_text = normalfont.render("By Rafa94", 8, (0, 66, 37))
        screen.blit(text, (35 - (text.get_width() / 5), 5))
        screen.blit(new_text, (300 - (text.get_width() / 5), 5))
        screen.blit(main_img, (5,340))
        screen.blit(main_img2, (85, 115))
        screen.blit(side_img, (330, 455))
        screen.blit(side_img2, (5, 445))


        button("GO!", 60, 40, 100, 50, DARK_BLUE, BLUE, "Play")
        button("QUIT!", 260, 40, 100, 50, LIGHT_RED, RED, "Quit")
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(15)


# Main game loop
def game_loop():
    global pause
    global playerCar_position, playerCar_position_two, playerCar_position_three, playerCar_position_four
    global playerY, playerY_two, playerY_three, playerY_four, playerX, playerX_two, playerX_three, playerX_four
    finish_line_rect = pygame.Rect(50, 70, 235, 32)
    finish_text = ""
    players_finished = 0
    next_level = 0
    time_to_blit = 0


    run = True
    while run:

        # Drawing on Screen
        screen.fill(BLACK)
        # Draw The Road
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, GREY, [40, 0, 300, 500])
        # Draw Line painting on the road
        pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [185, 0], [185, 500], 5)
        # Finish line
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLACKWHITE, [50, 50, 280, 40])
        pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [50, 70], [330, 70], 5)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", 20)
        text = font.render("Finish line!", 2, (150, 50, 25))
        screen.blit(text, (185 - (text.get_width() / 2), 45))
        screen.blit(bg, (-236, -34))
        screen.blit(bg, (-236, -5))
        screen.blit(bg, (-235, 140))
        screen.blit(bg, (-235, 240))
        screen.blit(bg, (-235, 340))
        screen.blit(bg, (340, -60))
        screen.blit(bg, (340, -60))
        screen.blit(bg, (335, 5))
        screen.blit(bg, (335, 130))
        screen.blit(bg, (335, 230))
        screen.blit(bg, (335, 330))
        screen.blit(bg, (333, 330))


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                # Number of frames per secong e.g. 60
                clock.tick(60)

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            if keys[pygame.K_1]:
                CarSound.play()
                playerCar_position = -0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_q]:
                playerCar_position = 0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_2]:
                CarSound_two.play()
                playerCar_position_two = -0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_w]:
                playerCar_position_two = 0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_3]:
                CarSound_three.play()
                playerCar_position_three = -0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_e]:
                playerCar_position_three = 0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_4]:
                CarSound_four.play()
                playerCar_position_four = -0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_r]:
                playerCar_position_four = 0.5
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                pause = True

                paused()




        # our functions
        playerY += playerCar_position
        playerY_two += playerCar_position_two
        playerY_three += playerCar_position_three
        playerY_four += playerCar_position_four

        player(playerX, playerY)
        player_two(playerX_two, playerY_two)
        player_three(playerX_three, playerY_three)
        player_four(playerX_four, playerY_four)



        # Did anyone cross the line?
        if (finish_line_rect.collidepoint(playerX, playerY)):
            if finish_text[:8] != "Player 1":  # so it doesnt do this every frame the car is intersecting
                finish_text = "Player 1 is " + placings[players_finished]
                players_finished += 1
                print("Player (one) has crossed into finish line!")
                Crowds.play()


        elif (finish_line_rect.collidepoint(playerX_two, playerY_two)):
            if finish_text[:8] != "Player 2":
                print("Player one has crossed into finish line first other car lost!")
                finish_text = "Player 2 is " + placings[players_finished]
                players_finished += 1
                Crowds_three.play()


        elif (finish_line_rect.collidepoint(playerX_three, playerY_three)):
            if finish_text[:8] != "Player 3":
                print("Player two has crossed into finish line first other car lost!")
                finish_text = "Player 3 is " + placings[players_finished]
                players_finished += 1

        elif (finish_line_rect.collidepoint(playerX_four, playerY_four)):
            if finish_text[:8] != "Player 4":
                print("Player two has crossed into finish line first other car lost!")
                finish_text = "Player 4 is " + placings[players_finished]
                players_finished += 1
                Crowds_two.play()

        if (players_finished and finish_text):
            #print("ft:", finish_text)

            font = pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", 17)
            textrect = font.render(finish_text, False, (0, 66, 37))
            #print('x', (SCREENWIDTH - text.get_width()) / 2)
            screen.blit(textrect, (65 - (text.get_width() / 5), -2))
            #screen.blit(textrect, ((SCREENWIDTH - textrect.get_width()) // 2, -5))

        if (finish_line_rect.collidepoint and players_finished):
            #pygame.mixer.final_tone.play(-1)
            final_tone.play()
            pygame.mixer.music.play(0)

        if (finish_text):
            font = pygame.font.SysFont("Impact", 20)
            text = font.render('Game Over!!!', 5, (0, 66, 37))
            screen.blit(text, (250 - (text.get_width() / 5), -2))

        if players_finished == 4:
            time_to_blit = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 5000

        if time_to_blit:
            screen.blit(text_two, (100, 345))
            #final_tone.play()
            if pygame.time.get_ticks() >= time_to_blit:
                time_to_blit = 0

        if players_finished == 4:
            next_level = 1

        score(players_finished)
        level(next_level)




        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

game_intro()





pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make everything you currently have for the level 1 specifically (track, soundtrack, etc) as a class of Level1. And create similar for Level2. Then in your game loop initialize level (for now it can be a global variable to look from, but it is suggested to have a Game object that has attributes like this encapsulated inside it) as Level1 while starting a new game. And when player is finished with level1 (handle the check inside Level1 class that way you can have different parameters of finishing on different levels), change the level to Level2.

What different things you need to keep in mind? Render your level based on currently selected level. Look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1873480/5830339) for some more insight.

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example? @Shafi

Comment: https://www.github.com/ankur0890/Pygame-Examples-For-Learning/tree/master/3%20Level%20Hungry%20Snake this has one very naive way of implementation. I personally have done this in pygame. But from my little experience with PyGame it can be done more efficiently. If I come with better example I will be sure to add